# Calculating the x and y of rotated image

Tags: c#, rotation

When we rotate any object like `Image` then its `x` and `y` will also change according to the

roation angle.[image]

I just want to know how we can calculate the outer rectangle `x` and `y` ( pointed with red

circle in the image ) while rotating the image. We have image `width`, `height` and

`rotation angle` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x - your x coordinate

height - height of your image

angle - rotation angle

Then you need **(x - height * sin(angle))**

Answer (score 0):

One usually uses a [Rotation Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) for such a thing.

> In linear algebra, a rotation matrix is a matrix that is used to
>   perform a rotation in Euclidean space

[This](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/LinAlg/LinearTransExamples.aspx) web page contains a section on rotation which should be useful to explain the concept.

Comment: Can tell how to apply rotation matrix to this task?